# "%" character cause Error in strings substitution with locals()

Tags: python, locals, string-substitution

I try to substitue strings with variables using locals() in python but I can find a way to use the **%** character inside the string without error.  Here is a concrete example :

```
color = colors_generator() #the function return a color

html = """<html><head>
<style>#square{color:%(color)s;width:100%;height:100%;}</style>    
</head>    <body>  <div id="square">  </div>
</body></html>""" % locals()

print "Content-Type: text/html\n"    
print html
```

Result : `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

The problem is the **%** character in **100%**.  How can I escape it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

escape % with %

```
html = """<html><head>
<style>#square{color:%(color)s;width:100%%;height:100%%;}</style>    
</head>    <body>  <div id="square">  </div>
</body></html>""" % locals()
```

Answer (score 1):

Virhilo has already answered your direct question, but if you find you are building quite big/complicated templates it might be worth looking at a full blown template engine instead:

- http://docs.python.org/library/string.html
- http://jinja.pocoo.org/
- http://www.makotemplates.org/